# Create an algorithm to alternate list items based on item type

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, grouping

I have to create a List alternating the items type.

In my original list, i have this:

Group - Type
Group1 - 1
Group2 - 2
Group3 - 1
Group4 - 1
Group5 - 1
Group6 - 2
Group7 - 3

And I want to reorganize the items in this way:

Group1 - 1
Group2 - 2
Group7 - 3
Group3 - 1
Group6 - 2
Group7 - 3
Group4 - 1
Group2 - 2
Group7 - 3
Group5 - 1
Group6 - 2
Group7 - 3

Understand? Based on the count of the type with more items, i need to alternate with the other items.

This algorithm need to englobe n types.

I'm a little bit lost, anyone can help me? What kind of algorithm is this an how to do it?

Comment: I guess you could group the list items according to type, making one list for each type. Then just iterate through these, wrapping around when needed.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost, too. You need to explain better what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my fist stab at this, though I'm sure this can be improved:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> AlternateGroups<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> list, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var groups = list.GroupBy(keySelector).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
    var largestGroup = groups.First();
    var arrays = groups.Skip(1).Select(g => g.ToArray());
    var index = new int[arrays.Count()];
    foreach(var item in largestGroup)
    {
        yield return item;
        var i = 0;
        foreach(var a in arrays)
        {
            yield return a[index[i++]++ % a.Length];
        }
    }
}
```

This is written as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx), which means you can call it like this:

```
var input = new[] 
{
    new { Group = "Group1", Type = 1 },
    new { Group = "Group2", Type = 2 },
    new { Group = "Group3", Type = 1 },
    new { Group = "Group4", Type = 1 },
    new { Group = "Group5", Type = 1 },
    new { Group = "Group6", Type = 2 },
    new { Group = "Group7", Type = 3 },
};

var results = input.AlternateGroups(x => x.Type);
// Group1 1 
// Group2 2 
// Group7 3 
// Group3 1 
// Group6 2 
// Group7 3 
// Group4 1 
// Group2 2 
// Group7 3 
// Group5 1 
// Group6 2 
// Group7 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much can this be performing, but should be functional:

Create an array of array in which you put the element of group I in array[i][j], so you should have something like

array[0]: Group1, Group3, Group4, Group5

array[1]: Group2, Group2

array[2]: Group3

then save for each array an index that points to the element just added

Finally, cycle between your row of array and the "columns", making an index restart from 0 when you reach the end of a sub-array. It's not beautiful but should work fine.

Sorry for my english, I hope you'll understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following works, although I am sure there are more elegant solutions.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments, I didn't realise that elements should be re-used from shorter lists to make up the length of the longest grouped list. Here's a revised version.

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Group>{
        new Group { Name = "Group1", Type = 1 },
        new Group { Name = "Group2", Type = 2 },
        new Group { Name = "Group3", Type = 1 },
        new Group { Name = "Group4", Type = 1 },
        new Group { Name = "Group5", Type = 1 },
        new Group { Name = "Group6", Type = 2 },
        new Group { Name = "Group7", Type = 3 }
    };

    var groups = list.GroupBy(g => g.Type).ToList();    
    var groupCounts = groups.Select(g => g.Count()).ToArray();  
    var biggestGroup = groupCounts.Max();

    var newList = new List<Group>();
    for (int i = 0; i < biggestGroup; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < groups.Count; j++)
        {
            var element = groups[j].ElementAt(i % groupCounts[j]);
            newList.Add(element);
        }
    }   

    // newList contains the ordered items
}

public class Group 
{
    public string Name { get;set; }

    public int Type { get;set; }
}
```

outputs

```
Group1 1 
Group2 2 
Group7 3 
Group3 1 
Group6 2 
Group7 3 
Group4 1 
Group2 2 
Group7 3 
Group5 1 
Group6 2 
Group7 3
```

You could make this into an extension method to return `IEnumerable<Group>` and `yield return` the items.

Comment: Does your input list have to have those extra 2 and 3s at the end to work correctly? The input in the question doesn't have it, it is expected to reuse some of the elements.

Comment: @Dukeling It doesn't need them no, but it will end up writing out the rest of the values that are left in each group. I didn't realise that it is expected to repeat values from groups.

Comment: @Dukeling updated. Just different code to do the same thing as p.s.w.g's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17225047/1831

Comment: Thank you guys! Sorry for the lack of details. My english isn't the best.

This code solve my problem very well!